# Replacing text in url after match template

Tags: regex, ruby

I have following url:  `https://domain.local/users/md43msdfmr45m`

Using regex I want to change to https://domain.local/users/hide-id

I wrote following regex matching template:

```
\/users\/+(.*)
```

To replace user id I use gsub method:

```
str.gsub!(/\/users\/+(.*)/, "hide-id")
```

But method replaces value after `https://domain.local`, but should be after `users/`

Comment: One way is to just do `str.gsub!(/\/users\/+(.*)/, "/users/hide-id")`

Comment: ...or `str.gsub(/(?<=\/users\/).*/, "hide-id")`, where `(?<=\/users\/)` is a *positive lookbehind*. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/canvLs/1)

Comment: Why `\/+` rather than just `\/`? Why the capture group `(.*)` rather than just `.*`?

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
str="https://domain.local/users/md43msdfmr45m"

p str.gsub(/(?<=users\/).*/,"hide-id")
```

Second way

```
replacement = "hide-id"
p str.gsub(%r{(\/users\/)\w+}, "\\1#{replacement}")
```

`%r{}` is an alternative to //

Output

```
https://domain.local/users/hide-id
```